# Problema con estilos CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Intento modificar la forma en la que veo un sitio web para eso cambio la referencia del atributo `href` por el que está almacenado en mi equipo; básicamente es el mismo archivo con una modificación por el momento; el problema es que al hacerlo pierdo por completo el estilo de la pagina.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].href = "http://127.0.0.1/Users/Maxi/Downloads/postcss-4e5c08be95c7e134a584e69258afd682.css"
```

Comment: Mira la consola de JavaScript y añade el error que ves cuando ejecutes ese comando. Seguramente genera un 404.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Alvaro, es cierto genera un error de conexión, pero de todas formas aplica el cambio que hice en CSS y no todo lo demás, la pagina queda sin formatos.

Comment: Pero eso es el problema: cambias la ruta del CSS correctamente con JS, pero a una dirección que no existe y eso hace que falle y no veas los estilos. Intenta cambiar la URL de `"http://127.0.0.1/Users/Maxi/Downloads/postcss-4e5c08be95c7e134a584e69258afd682.css"` a `"file:///C:/Users/Maxi/Downloads/postcss-4e5c08be95c7e134a584e69258afd682.css"` (si estás en la unidad C:) y mira a ver si eso te funciona.

Comment: Sucede lo mismo, solo que además tengo el error de que no está permitido cargar recursos locales. Puede ser algo más que la ruta lo que esté faltando?

Comment: El problema es que no estás referenciando bien el fichero, ¿tienes un servidor web corriendo en local?

Comment: No, no utilizo servidor web. Acabo de hacer una prueba que confirma lo que dices, es un problema de referencias 100%

Comment: Sin un servidor local, la dirección 127.0.0.1 no va a funcionar. Debes montar un servidor o instalar algún plugin que te sirva para remplazar enlaces en sitios web por ficheros locales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que estás apuntando a una dirección que no existe. El cambio en el JS se está haciendo bien y el código es correcto, pero la URL proporcionada no es correcta:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Users/Maxi/Downloads/postcss-4e5c08be95c7e134a584e69258afd682.css
```

esa URL está apuntando a un servidor local pero, a no ser que la raíz de tu servidor local sea la unidad principal de tu ordenador (cosa que dudo), esa dirección no es válida. Por lo que vas a recibir un error 404. Además, [por lo que indicas en tus comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139320/problema-con-estilos-css?noredirect=1#comment260296_139320), no estás usando un servidor local, por lo que la dirección 127.0.0.1 ni siquiera funcionará porque no existe.

Una solución sería montar un servidor local (es algo que puedes hacer en cuestión de minutos con [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com) o [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)), hacer que corra, poner el archivo CSS en ese servidor local y apuntar a ese archivo.

Alternativamente, te recomendaría usar alguna herramienta/plugin para el navegador como [Resource Override](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii?hl=es) (para Chrome) o [PourBico](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/pourbico/) (para Firefox, éste no lo he usado antes), que te permitirá reemplazar recursos de un sitio web por archivos locales sin problemas.

Comment: Te agradezco, con esa información seguro pueda solucionarlo.

Comment: @MaximilianoAlfonso prueba y me dices si necesitas ayuda. Wamp se instala en 2 segundos y es super fácil de usar. Sólo tendrías que instalarlo, arrancar el programa (sin necesidad de reiniciar Windows), mover tu fichero a c:\wamp\www y apuntarlo desde tu JS.

Comment: obtuve resultados creando un servidor web local con Wamp y modificando algunos aspectos de la hoja de estilos original, pero quiero automatizar esto para convertirlo en un userscript de Tampermonkey sin tener que hacer uso de toda la StyleSheet; tu solución es buena pero la puedo aplicar solamente en el ámbito local.